# Get all the events bound by .on() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a page load some contents by Ajax, and also bind events via `.on()` method to the new comming elements.

Is there anyway to get all the binding events on `<div class="inner">`?
I've try `$("div.inner").data('events')` in the console **after all contents loaded**,
but there is nothing but `undefined`.

Html:

```
<div id="out"><p></p></div>​
```

JavaScript: (not really ajax, just a simulation)

```
var innDiv = '<div class="inner">inner</div>' +
'<div class="inner">inner</div>' +
'<div class="inner">inner</div>';

$(document).on('click','.inner', function(){$(this).toggleClass("green")});

setTimeout('$("#out").append(innDiv)',2000);​
```

Here is the [jsfiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/vcX7k/) demo.

Comment: The events in your example are bound to `document` not `.inner`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you bound your events to `document` element, try this:

```
$(document).data("events")
```

Answer (score 4):

From jQuery 1.8, the $(element).data("events") was removed. But for debugging purposes, use `$._data(element, "events")` can get the events binding on the elements. Since it's not a public interface, this might not work in the future.

Check the jQuery release log [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, in that case, if it is a live event.

```
$('.target').live('click', function foo(){  });
```

or

```
$('containerObj').on('click', 'target', function foo(){  });
```

you might have to check the events data of the object you are binding live event to.

if it is at the document level you might have to check events of document object or else the target container on which the event is bound to. i.e.

to remove the live attached event from an element you do.

```
$('containerObj').off('click', 'target', function foo(){  });
```

hope it helps.

Comment: That's what he already did: *"I've try $("div.inner").data('events')"* and it did not work.

Comment: check now, hope it helps now.